# Convergence of parametric series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am stuck with the following

**Exercise.**
Discuss the convergence of the following series, 
$$ 
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\Big[\Big(\frac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]
$$
where $x$ is varying in $\mathbb{R}$. I tried some manipulations on the general term, hoping to use some asymptotics, without success. For example, I tried the following
$$
\Big[\Big(\frac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]=\Big[\Big(\frac{n^x-n+1+2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]=\Big[\Big(1+\frac{2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]=\Big[e^{2n\ln\Big(1+\frac{2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)}-1\Big]=...
$$
How could I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

I get that it diverges for
$x \le 3$ and converges for
$x > 3$.

The basic inequality
for proving divergence is Bernoulli's:
$(1+x)^n \ge 1+nx$
if $n \ge 1$ and $x \ge -1$.

You have
$\Big[\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]
=\Big[\Big(\dfrac{n^x-n+1+2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]
=\Big[\Big(1+\dfrac{2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}-1\Big]
$.

If $x \lt 1$ then
$n^x-n+1 < 0$
so

$\begin{array}\\
\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}
&=\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n-n^x+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(\dfrac{n-n^x+1+2n^x+6}{n-n^x+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(1+\dfrac{2n^x+6}{n-n^x+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&\ge1+\dfrac{(2n)(2n^x+6)}{n-n^x+1}\\
&\gt 3
\qquad\text{for large }n\\
\end{array}
$
so the sum diverges.

If $x = 1$ then

$\begin{array}\\
\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}
&=\Big(2n+7\Big)^{2n}\\
\end{array}\\
$

which diverges.

If $x > 1$ then
$x = 1+c$ for $c > 0$ so

$\begin{array}\\
\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}
&=\Big(\dfrac{n^x-n+1+2n+6}{n-n^x+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(1+\dfrac{2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(1+\dfrac{2+6/n}{n^{x-1}-1+1/n}\Big)^{2n}\\
&\approx\Big(1+\dfrac{2}{n^{c}}\Big)^{2n}\\
&\ge 1+\dfrac{4n}{n^{c}}\\
&= 1+\dfrac{4}{n^{c-1}}\\
\end{array}
$

so if $c-1 \le 1$
(i.e., $x \le 3$)
the sum diverges.

If
$c-1 > 1$, or $x > 3$,
then

$\begin{array}\\
\Big(\dfrac{n^x+n+7}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}
&=\Big(\dfrac{n^x-n+1+2n+6}{n-n^x+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(1+\dfrac{2n+6}{n^x-n+1}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=\Big(1+\dfrac{2+6/n}{n^{x-1}-1+1/n}\Big)^{2n}\\
&\approx\Big(1+\dfrac{2}{n^{c}}\Big)^{2n}\\
&=e^{2n\ln(1+2/n^c)}\\
&\le e^{2n(2/n^c)}
\qquad\text{since } \ln(1+z) < z\\
&= e^{4/n^{c-1}}\\
&\lt 1+8/n^{c-1}
\qquad\text{for large enough }n\\
\end{array}
$

and the sum of this converges.